# "FPeval" along with "clip" when multiplied with 10 gives wrong answer while it does not happen with other numbers

Tags: fp, clip, xfp

```
\newcounter{tenMarksQ}
\setcounter{tenMarksQ}{0}
\DTLforeach{Q}{\Marks=Marks}
{
    \ifnum\Marks=10
    \addtocounter{tenMarksQ}{1}
    \fi
}
\FPeval{\10}{clip(10*\thetenMarksQ)}
\section{ELABORATE ON: \hfill $\text{\thetenMarksQ\times10}=\text{\10}$}
\begin{questions}
\DTLforeach{Q}{\Marks=Marks, \Question=Question,
\Subquestion=Subquestion}
{\ifnum\Marks=10
    \question \Question
    \ifx\Subquestion\empty 
        \else
        \begin{parts}
            \part \Subquestion
        \end{parts}
    \fi
\fi
}
\end{questions}
```

the above code is working great for 3 marks, 5 marks but when it comes to 10 marks the number of question(here,4) multiplied with 10 gives 400, but I anticipated to get 40.
[image]

Comment: You can't use `\10`. Legal control sequences have either letters only or a single nonletter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in using `\10`. A shortened version showing the same problem is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}

\begin{document}

\FPeval{\10}{clip(10*4)}

\10

\end{document}
```

which produces

400

Why? Because you cannot define a macro `\10`. Macro names can be of two flavors: either letters only or a single nonletter.

In your case, the result of the operation is stored in `\1` and the `0` is lost for reasons of how `\FPeval` is implemented.

Next, when you do `\10`, the value stored in `\1` is printed and it is 40; then TeX typesets the `0`.

Use something like `\byten` or whatever.

Well, you *might* use `10` as a command name, but only inside the `\csname...\endcsname` construct. This would work:

```
\expandafter\FPeval\csname 10\endcsname{clip(10*4)}

\csname 10\endcsname
```

but are you wanting to do that just for the sake of having a macro with that name?

By the way, you shouldn't use `\thetenMarksQ`, but `\arabic{tenMarksQ}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}

\newcounter{tenMarksQ}
\setcounter{tenMarksQ}{4}

\begin{document}

\FPeval{\byten}{clip(10*\arabic{tenMarksQ})}

\byten

\end{document}
```

This will print 40.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, you guys are always better than AIs.